# Why python keeps looking for 2.7 on OSX Mojave?

Tags: python, macos

I did a pip3 install virtualenv, and as soon as I try to create a virtualenv -p python3...

I get:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resour: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

How to fix this so it is using the python3.6 on my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `virtualenv` command, you could use `python3 -m virtualenv env`.